# Why ArrayList only uses first element

Tags: java, arraylist, chess

I have been writing this class for an assignment. My question is when I call ArrayList.add() method, why is it keep updating element 0 instead of adding it at the end. I read ArrayList entry on docs, I tried to use the method ArrayList.add(index, element) instead, result didn't change.

for `new BlackBishop(7,3);` (7 is for row 7 of chess board and 3 for column C)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BlackBishop extends Item{

BlackBishop(int y, int x){
    name='F';
    point=3;
    this.y=y;
    this.x=x;
    availableMoves();
}

public ArrayList<Integer[]> availableMoves(){
    int finalY=0;
    int finalX=0;
    Integer[] move=new Integer[2];
    ArrayList<Integer[]> avMoves=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=1;i<8;i++){
        if(x-i>0&&y-i>0){
            finalY=y-i;
            finalX=x-i;
            move[0]=finalY;
            move[1]=finalX;
            avMoves.add(move);
        }
        System.out.println(avMoves.get(0)[0]+" "+avMoves.get(0)[1]);
        if(x-i>0&&y+i<=8){
            finalY=y+i;
            finalX=x-i;
            move[0]=finalY;
            move[1]=finalX;
            avMoves.add(move);
        }
        System.out.println(avMoves.get(0)[0]+" "+avMoves.get(0)[1]);
        if(x+i<=8&&y-i>0){
            finalY=y-i;
            finalX=x+i;
            move[0]=finalY;
            move[1]=finalX;
            avMoves.add(move);
        }
        if(x+i<=8&&y+i<=8){
            finalY=y+i;
            finalX=x+i;
            move[0]=finalY;
            move[1]=finalX;
            avMoves.add(move);
        }
        
    }
    return avMoves;
}
}
```

Output:

```
6 2
8 2
5 1
5 1
5 5
5 5
4 6
4 6
3 7
3 7
2 8
2 8
2 8
2 8
```

Comment: You need to write `move = new Integer[2]` every time you add it to the list.

Comment: Thank you @LouisWasserman, in that case, I guess then I indeed don't need an Integer[] variable at all, `avMoves.add(new Integer[2]);` will do.

Comment: Move `Integer[] move=new Integer[2];` inside your loop (at its start). Otherwise you will be adding to `avMoves` reference to *same* `movie` array many times. This means that `avMoves` will hold *same* array object many times, so when you modify that object, that change will be visible from each "element" of list.

Comment: Well, you have to still set its values.

Comment: I completely got rid of array variable and added a `new Integer[2]` and **then** set the `finalX` `finalY` values in each if branch. Thanks for the aid.